# Why Are These Imports Errored?

Tags: java, netbeans, import

As part of my uni project, I have had to clone a group member's code and work on it myself. But on the imports included below, they are underlined and I can't seem to know why or how to address this. Netbeans says that these are 'Unused imports'. I've already tried to Google this but with no luck.

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Please bear with me as I am completely new to programming and it's concepts. Thank you.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import static org.apache.http.HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT;
```

Comment: Just remove them - your IDE tells you they are unused.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, "Unused import" is a message from the IDE (not directly related to Java) and means that you're not using that class/interface/whatever it is. Also, note that this is a warning, not an error. This means, your code can compile and execute without issues.

To fix this, just remove the unused import statements.

Example of how to raise unused import:

```
package something;

//this interface is never used in this class
import java.util.List;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Example of how to fix it:

```
package something;
//removed import java.util.List; since it's not used

public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```